# WCF REST - maxMessageSize exceeded

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

Here are parts of the configuration file:

```
<services>
  <service name="MMC.API2.MMCApi" behaviorConfiguration="restBehaviorConfig">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MMC.API2.IMMCApi" behaviorConfiguration="web" bindingConfiguration="LargeData">
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <timeouts openTimeout="01:20:00" closeTimeout="01:20:00" />
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

...

```
     <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LargeData" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="32" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
```

Problem:

**The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.**

Comment: Try increasing your httpRunTime maxRequestLength in your web.config

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me. Try to change the behavior configuration as below;

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="true" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="00:10:00" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentSessions="100"
        maxConcurrentInstances="100" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: Maybe reason is system web tag ?  <httpRuntime targetFramework="x" maxRequestLength="2000000" /> in system.web tag

Answer (score 0):

The fragments of the service’s binding configuration seem to be set ok, so you may want to look into the clients’ binding configurations to make sure they have similar settings for the `readerQuotas` and maxBuffer* settings.

Notes:
You may want to provide a bit more information about the overall environment/configuration.
If you haven’t already, enabling WCF trace logging may help you identify the issue.

Comment: The WCF REST service is activated by an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: The ASP.NET MVC application should use a binding configuration similar to the "LargeData" binding definition.

Comment: What I have posted is part of ASP.NET MVC web.config file.